# HOCON Key Substitution

Tags: hocon

Is there anyway we can substitute key in HOCON config files? Below is what I have right now:

```
config1 {
 "foo" : "bar"
}
```

And I'm trying to achieve :

```
config1 {
 ${keyVariable} : ${valueVariable}
}
```

Value substitution is supported but I couldn't find any key substitution doc. And if it is not supported, is there any work around that's doable? Thank you guys!